# lua の string.gsub で 小カッコ入り文字列が置換できない

Tags: nginx, lua

lua で `url(imga` という文字列を `url(image` に書き換えたく、以下のように書いたんですが置換されません。

例1:

```
string.gsub(str, 'url(imga', 'url(image')
```

以下のように書き換えたところエラーとなってダメでした。
どなたかご教示の程よろしくお願い致します。

例2:

```
string.gsub(str, 'url\(imga', 'url\(image')
```

※OpenRestyにてnginx.conf内body_filter_by_lua_block中で書いたluaです。
　もし普通のluaと違ったらすみません。

Answer (score 0):

`%` で `(` をエスケープします。

```lua
$ lua
Lua 5.4.6  Copyright (C) 1994-2023 Lua.org, PUC-Rio

> str = 'url(imga'
> x = string.gsub(str, "url%(imga", "url(image")
> x
url(image
```

Comment: パパパパーセントでしたか！大変ありがとうございました。